# Can you identify this logo?

Tags: identification

Can you identify the logo on these ICs?

[image]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[image]

Micro Power Systems: http://www.datasheetarchive.com/pdf-datasheets/Datasheets-111/DSAP0025577.html

Comment: I knew it was the "M" from Micro, but the rest... :-). Damn Quick Answer, BTW. Thanks.