# Identifying manufacturer logos on components

Tags: components

This question is inspired by [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/7637/1240) question.

I'm interested in on-line resources which can be used to identify logos. Are there any databases of commonly and not so commonly used logos on ICs which can help there?

I know that http://www.datasheetcatalog.com/ brings up logos of manufacturers when searching for datasheet, but it happened to me few times that I was looking for a component with unknown manufacturer and none on the logos matched.

Comment: Could you (well, a mod) make this CW and people could add a logo per answer, maybe include a link to the mfc's website?  Not sure if that would be a proper use

Comment: CW = continuous wave? Clockwise?

Comment: @stevenvh CW = Community wiki. It means that almost anyone can edit the question and answers.  It is also used when the question doesn't actually have an answer (like this one) and needs long discussion or lots of answers. @Nick T I think that the idea is good and agree on the CW part. I flagged it for CW, so hopefully we'll see results soon.

Comment: Community wikified!

Comment: Cross-linking for readers / algorithm: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/334128/how-do-i-identify-smd-components-or-how-do-i-identify-any-component

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've found this link at Google: http://www.advanced-tech.com/ic_logos/ic_logos.htm (dead link and domain, which is [available via the Internet Archive from November 2013](https://web.archive.org/web/20131107014008/http://www.advanced-tech.com/ic_logos/ic_logos.htm))

Comment: Looks very interesting!

Comment: http://www.chipdocs.com/logos/logotypes.html http://www.elnec.com/support/ic-logos/

Comment: That URL is dead. Site does not load.

Comment: @endolith, I've moved both of the answers in your comment into their own answers, seeing as they're still working (as is only 1 of the other answers!)

Answer (score 4):

http://www.westfloridacomponents.com/manufacturer-logos.html (dead link) featured logos for around 400 manufacturers, alphabetically by company.

The last capture I could find of it is https://web.archive.org/web/20170817083634/https://www.westfloridacomponents.com/manufacturer-logos.html

[The PDF version linked from that page](https://www.westfloridacomponents.com/mm5/graphics/manufacturer-logos.pdf) is a printout of the same page from 2009-05-28.

Answer (score 2):

The [IC Photos](http://www.icphotos.org/) site is also a useful tool for this type of effort.

Comment: That URL is dead. Site does not load.

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty comprehensive overview: http://info.electronicwerkstatt.de/bereiche/bauteile/ic_logo/

Answer (score 0):

From [endolith's](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/142/endolith) [comment](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/7641/identifying-manufacturer-logos-on-components#comment10639_7643) on another answer:

http://www.chipdocs.com/logos/logotypes.html

Answer (score 0):

From [endolith's](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/142/endolith) [comment](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/7641/identifying-manufacturer-logos-on-components#comment10639_7643) on another answer:

https://www.elnec.com/en/support/ic-logos/

Answer (score 0):

Seen in [Ken Shirriff's tweet](https://twitter.com/kenshirriff/status/1741661696320766233), a list of Russian logos: https://madelectronics.ru/book/prominfo/2009-04-16-08-29-39-318.htm