# What is this UP 4B2 smd chip in dfn8 case?

Tags: dc-motor, driver, surface-mount, darlington

[image: Found on a decoder for digital model trains.]

Acts probably as a driver to power the motor. There a two of this kind on the board. One burned, the train drives only in one direction.

Comment: Welcome to SE EE, unfortunately questions like this (where can I buy this component?) are off topic, see: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: Okay, I revised it.

Comment: I can't tell what I see here. It might as well be a fet or transistor. Can you post a *sharp* photo of a larger area of the board the chip is used on? Or trace some of the signals going to it, that would certainly help matching pin-outs.

Comment: Related: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/334128/how-do-i-identify-smd-components-or-any-component

Answer (score 0):

[image: The decoder]

I searched ebay for "darlington dfn8" and found a "AON 7200" chip. A 30V N-Channel MOS-FET, where 4 pins of one side are internally connected. So I have to measure if it is this type. Tecnically it might be that...

Comment: Draw circuit diagram basing on the board layout and component pinout and share it. People will be able to give you better idea then.