# Mystery component

Tags: surface-mount, component-failure

I have this SMD component that popped. I cant seem to identify it properly. Could you please help? I tried to look it up, but had no luck. It is a led driver board. [image: led driver]

Comment: MOV, Sidac, or TVS perhaps ?

Comment: whatever it is, chances are this is by far not the only component that died that day – this looks rather hefty.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I think you are right. Look at the part to the left of it, parallel arranged. The top of that one doesn't look all that good, either. Could be spatter. But...

Comment: My guess would be a TVS diode, but no idea on the rating. As @MarcusMüller says, it's a powerful component in parallel with multiple powerful components. But it is a protection device, so might be almost sacrificial.

Comment: That is the Bourns logo.

Comment: Bourns part, marked BP. Could be a [SMBJ16CA](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/54/mbj-778392.pdf) TVS diode. Check if the package dimensions match, though.

Comment: Related: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/334128/how-do-i-identify-smd-components-or-any-component