# Help identifying component on cisco switch SGD110D-08

Tags: identification

first of all thanks for taking time helping me with this issue.

TL;DR; Identify the blew up component on the picture and win!

I've by mistake done a very short but effective connection in reverse polarity to my cisco switch. Apparently only one component blew up and I pretend to replace it and see if I can save the switch as it is brand new.

During the "explosion"  of the component part of it's name got deleted but I'm pretty sure that someone with more experience (or maybe someone with the same switch and good will) can help me identify the component.

Here's the best picture I can take:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7b52i.jpg

Here's the whole PCB for some context:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYGJp.jpg

The model is SG110D-08 it's a 8-port gigabit switch.

Thanks!

EDIT 1:

New photo cleaned up with some alcohol.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/o71S8.jpg

Comment: I think it's more then 1 the blew up....

Comment: Wow! That let out all the smoke and more. Sorry to say so but I think the board may be charred in that same area, as in not usable. Clean that up with alcohol and a cue-tip and look for charred spots. If there are any the board cannot be repaired.

Comment: New picture cleaned up... There's some char... But as I don't have much more to loose I'm willing to try anything, at least as a educational experiment ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @NoName13 Related: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/334128/how-do-i-identify-smd-components-or-any-component/334129#334129

Comment: Very useful, I should have searched for it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't tell for sure, as the marking is burned off (but looks like AG_ maybe) - but the layout example in the TI TPS562200 datasheet looks damn near identical to what's on that pcb: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps562200.pdf

Comment: It does look like it, I've added a new picture cleaned up. As commented I might not be able to replace the component due the damage on the board but if I can identify it better maybe I can wire a external regulator... Thank you very  much for your help identifying it.

Comment: It was a 3v3 regulator. I will go to sleep now because I discovered that trying 5v first and smoking the main IC :D. Thanks,