# I'm trying to identify this SMD

Tags: identification, surface-mount

I'm trying to repair Black and Decker Thermal Leak Detector. I was testing the 9v input from the battery when I notices the chip was cracked. I'm thinking it is a transistor, but I haven't been able to cross reference it. Any help would be grateful.[image]

Comment: Sorry, component U1

Comment: U1 usually designates an IC ... transistors are usually Q1 ... but the manufacturer may have decided otherwise ... a schematic would be helpful.  .... please add information about the model number to your question .... do not add info to comments as you have done above

Comment: http://www.s-manuals.com/pdf/datasheet/b/g/bga6289_nxp.pdf

Comment: @G36 given the context that this is from a drill a microwave part seems rather unlikely.

Comment: Looks like they decided to save a penny and left out the reverse battery protection. Chances are this is a voltage regulator (linear or switching) but it's hard to tell from the part number.

Comment: @PeterGreen It's an IR thermometer by the looks of it. No microwaves.

Comment: @TomRasmussen Related: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/334128/how-do-i-identify-smd-components-or-any-component/334129#334129