# Identify manufacturer and chip

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification

I'm trying to identify the manufacturer and component from a Belkin tunecast (Lightning) to FM transmitter device. I've searched through a couple of logo sites and Google and was not successful.

The part number being only numbers does not help either :(

[image: Grainy image of chip with logo (arrow bent into a circle) and numbers 8006, 391431, UU08]

Comment: As usual, context would help.

Comment: As Marcus says. We need to know where you found the chip (what product), more details on the surrounding circuitry (a photo), and possibly even an approximate dimension.

Comment: This is in a Belkin tunecast (Lightning) to FM transmitter device.
I figured for identification purposes (especially the logo) context would not matter. I'll remember next time to add more information.

Comment: @Jacques For future reference: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/334128/how-do-i-identify-smd-components-or-any-component

Answer (score 16):

It's a [Quintic QN8006B](http://www.datasheetspdf.com/datasheet/download.php?id=913905) High Performance Digital FM Transceiver in a QFN-24 type package.

[image: QN8006 Functional Block Diagram]
<sup>Image from datasheet linked above.</sup>

For confirmation, here is a picture of one:
[image]

<sup>[Image Source](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/QN8006B-QUINTIC-QN8006-8006-QFN24/32781003451.html)</sup>

Comment: There's so many semiconductor companies that I've never heard of. This particular one has practically only one product, FM chips, since 2015 NXP seems to have bought the bluetooth division.

Comment: Thank you Tom, you found the needle in the haystack. Out of curiosity, how/where did you find this?

Comment: Not sure how Tom did it, but when I search google for "FM transmitter 8006 chip" it's the 4th result.

Comment: @Jacques I typed "QFN24 8006" into Google.