# SMD transistor marking

Tags: transistors, identification, surface-mount, markings

I have a SOT-23 SMD transistor marked "2.X L" as shown in the image.
[image]

I managed to find out that "2X" stands for 2N4401 and the dot seems to mean "lead free". But I couldn't find the meaning of the perpendicular "L". I think it could be a "date code" but I'm not sure and I don't know either what its purpose is (e.g. does it affect the pinout?).
I would appreciate any help.

Regards

Comment: Related: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/334128/how-do-i-identify-smd-components-or-any-component

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a date/manufacturing code. Does not change pinout in any way.

Look at this datasheet:https://www.mouser.com/ds/2/308/MMBT4401LT1-D-108598.pdf

[image: Marking diagram]