# What IC is this?

Tags: integrated-circuit

This IC must be a timer which is found in a flowmeter. Can anyone help me identify it.

Things written on it are         397C1
                                 3310D
                                 1611CM

[image]

Comment: Why do you think "it must be a timer"? It's much more likely to be an MCU.

Comment: Related: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/334128/how-do-i-identify-smd-components-or-any-component

Comment: Those 'JTAG pins' are badly soldered (at least that's what I presume them to be)

Comment: The circuit has MSP430 so I dont think so think is an MCU.

Comment: @laptop2d Could those be press-fit connectors? I've never seen them personally, so just a wild guess ;)

Comment: Next time try typing the numbers into google. It came up first hit....

Answer (score 9):

It's a nordic semiconductor bluetooth chip. I don't know exactly which one, but if you want you can look through all their datasheets to find the product markings, and one of them will match up. There's also a chip antenna at the top of the picture.

Comment: Is it really a chip antenna? Looks to me like one of these 32-ish kHz crystal packages. Its placement also doesn't scream _antenna_ to me.