# Identify SMT Component ".K13"

Tags: pcb

I check online for this .K13 SMC but I can not find the same component. Does anyone have a chance to work with this component? In the document, the package has 6 pins but the photo only has 5 pins.

http://m.alldatasheetit.com/datasheet-pdf/pdf/928469/BILIN/MMDT4413.html

[image: The package showed.k13]

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you think this datasheet describes this component on the picture? Generally it is near to impossible to know what this component is without understanding where it is installed. The best for you is to obtain circuit diagram (service manual) for the device and identify component using it. At least you must share more information about device here, with pictures of the board from both sides, then colleagues may try giving you a guess.

Comment: No, I have not had a chance to work with this component. If you have a specific question, please edit your question.

Comment: @Jack for future reference: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/334128/how-do-i-identify-smd-components-or-any-component

Answer (score 1):

Could be TSV6191AICT, a CMOS amplifier.

http://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/tsv6191.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Could be a [Ricoh RP112N131B](https://pdf.datasheet.live/datasheets-1/ricoh/RP112N271D-TR-FE.pdf), though the pin 4 connection suggests otherwise.