# What kind of capacitor might this be? Value?

Tags: capacitor, identification

I am trying to duplicate a simple 556 circuit, this capacitor works, but when I try to substitute another cap, it doesn't work.  I need to order a couple dozen of these but want to order the right thing:)  tha cal in question is the flat green one with 103k in the number.
I tried to measure this cap with my vom, and it read .025n.
I dont know , that is accurate, since the .025n stays on my meter display with other components and wont zero out till I change away from capacitance and back again.[image: enter )![enter image description here]

Thanks,

Dan[image]

Comment: For future reference: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/334128/how-do-i-identify-smd-components-or-how-do-i-identify-any-component

Answer (score 3):

That looks like a .01uF (10nF) 100V film cap. The code is 103K, you can find a chart of capacitor codes here:

https://tubeamplifierparts.com/handy-amp-info/capacitor-code-chart.html

Comment: I'll look them up, appreciate your advice.

Comment: @danielphantom can you please click accept this answer?

Also you'll have an easy time finding these on [Mouser](https://www.mouser.com/) or [Digi-Key](https://www.digikey.com/) with their filters. Just look under passive components>capacitors>film capacitors and select .01uF for capacitance and 100V for DC voltage rating.