# Help Identify a Connector Type for Beats Solo 2

Tags: connector, identification

I have a broken Beats Solo 2 headphone where the only broken/missing component is a connector that I cannot identify. [image] I've obtained a picture of the headphone from a tear-down of the headphones and circled the connector in gray.

Comment: there are 6 pins for the connector.

Comment: Related: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/334128/how-do-i-identify-smd-components-or-how-do-i-identify-any-component/334129#334129

Comment: looks like a small Molex connector or something similar. Are you sure the connector is what failed though? Seems kind of unlikely to me unless you were poking around a lot in there and messing with it.

Comment: Someone asked me to fix it and said someone threw it across the room. The picture above is not a picture of the broken headphone. I just looked around the internet for the connector that was missing from the broken headphone.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a molex connector socket.

I'm not sure if it is an jumper 8 or picoblade.

Finding similar connectors on google, I find this sockets [image: sockets]

Here: http://www.micronradiocontrol.co.uk/conn_wiring.html

Hope it helps