# 6 pin SMD IC marking code ADS

Tags: integrated-circuit, markings

Please help me to identify 6 pin SMD IC with top marking ADS[image]

Comment: Related: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/334128/how-do-i-identify-smd-components-or-how-do-i-identify-any-component/334129#334129

Comment: Opamp MAX9617 could be