# ADC IC identification

Tags: power-supply, power, adc

I'm struggling to identify the origin of the IC in the attached image. I believe it is a rebadged HP/Agilent part:1826-1488, ADC CMOS 12-BIT 20-PIN. can you tell from the logo who makes it then I can try to track the original part number and perhaps find a replacement part if no longer in production.

it's in a HP system power supply (HP 6624A).

[image]

Comment: That looks like an old National Semiconductor logo.

Comment: It's a National Semi logo, with an Agilent/HP internal part number. That means National made a "custom" version (maybe just modified test parameters, or maybe just custom marking, maybe a completely custom design) for HP/Agilent.

Comment: @brhans I would think it's Analog Devices (AD). Unless it is explicitly telling us it is an ADC...

Comment: TI bought NSC look there

Comment: @EugeneSh. [old natsemi logo](https://www.google.com/search?q=national+semiconductor+logo&tbm=isch&source=iu&ictx=1&fir=rETldVdz4Uj-CM%253A%252CpKy9dsym-8gvtM%252C_&usg=__vqSRfPfUuB5HTYmzjAvXMYFe-0o%3D&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi6xqDKtczbAhWro1kKHWcxBuQQ9QEIMTAD#imgrc=rETldVdz4Uj-CM:)

Comment: @EugeneSh., I dunno what the "AD" stands for, but compare it to this part: http://www.cpu-world.com/CPUs/32016/National%20Semiconductor-NS32016N-10%20(NS16032N-10).html

Comment: @ThePhoton Pretty convincing :)

Comment: @P0B Related: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/334128/how-do-i-identify-smd-components-or-how-do-i-identify-any-component/334129#334129

Comment: The current [service manual](https://literature.cdn.keysight.com/litweb/pdf/06626-90003.pdf?id=1000002468-1:epsg:man) for the 6624A gives cross references for many of the parts, but I don't see 1826-1488 listed there. The only ADC that's called out is an AD7534. That is a 14-bit rather than 12-bit part, but it is available in the same 20-pin DIP as your part. Maybe they're now using the AD part because the old NS part is obsolete --- you could check to see if the pin-out of the AD7534 makes sense in your circuit.

Comment: Might be a custom part, I can't find a trace of it

Comment: Just realized, the AD7534 is used at the exact same designator (U321) in the newer 6625A where your mystery part is used in the 6624A. Again, I'd check if the AD7534 pin-out makes sense in the older design.

Comment: @the photon , the part is listed in the service manual: http://ridl.cfd.rit.edu/products/manuals/Agilent/power%20supplies/CD1/Service/6621Aser.pdf    page 5-21 , U313

Comment: @PDB, but there's no cross-reference to the manufacturer PN. In the Service Manual for the newer design (linked above), they cross-reference to the AD part I mentioned. But obviously that is a different design, since it's a 14-bit ADC instead of 12-bit. So you're going to have to do some work yourself to see if the new part can be used in the old board.

Comment: Now that @crj has located a cross-reference, it doesn't look like it would be easy to use the AD part as a replacement for the NS one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct about the HP part number.  The cross reference from [this HP cross reference guide](https://doc.xdevs.com/doc/HP_Agilent_Keysight/HP%20Master%20Xref.pdf) is shown below.  Note that it is marked as "SELECTED".  This means that it was a selected for specific characteristics, as described in the second snippet from the document shown below.

The part is apparently out of production, but there are a few of the National Semiconductor version currently on eBay.  They have a 1989 date code, but are listed as unused.

[Here](https://www.cselettronica.com/datasheet/DAC1231.pdf) is a link to the datasheet for the National Semiconductor part.

[image]

[image]

Comment: So it looks like the OP needs to source an old DAC1230, and that it's a DAC, not an ADC.