# how to identify transistor/IC by its model/product number?

Tags: transistors

How to identify(biasing/company/working sections) transistor / IC by its model/product number? or details ?Example: 2sc2078, 2n2219 etc.

Please help, i need to understand...

Thanks

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/334128/how-do-i-identify-smd-components-or-how-do-i-identify-any-component/334129#334129

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do a web search for "[part number] datasheet".  For example, searching for "2N3904 datasheet" should lead you to datasheets for a 2N3904 transistor.

The transistor and diode part numbers appear to just be randomly assigned numbers, with no inherent meaning.

Comment: thanks but is there any other way(without searching data sheet).

Comment: actually i want understand by seeing part no, is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

You can do a web search.

For 2SC etc. numbers I use some printed Japanese reference material (Transistor Manual bought in Akihabara) listing EIAJ (now JEITA) registered parts which shows, for example, 2SC2078 was originally manufactured by "三洋" (Sanyo Electric Co., Ltd., now owned by Panasonic, formerly Matsushita) but if you search online the Sanyo datasheet will show up even more easily.

Comment: thanks, i want to know actually what s,c, are stands for?

Comment: It's just a part of the number 2SC are NPN Japanese BJTs. 2SA are PNP. Transistors start with a '2S'. Sometimes the 2S is omitted, so we have C1815 = 2SC1815 (common NPN transistor) or A1015 - 2SA1015 (common PNP). A&B are PNP, C&D are NPN, F = SCR, H = UJT, I think, J = P FET, K = N FET M = triac.

Comment: thanks a lot sir. do you have any link / video ,to more about this sections?

Comment: I think the European transistor part number prefix ("BC" in BC123, for example) also gives some indication of the general type of the part - a web search for "European transistor numbers" or similar may yield some useful information.