# What are these SOT23-5 components marked 7HUH and AAPQ?

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification

I am doing a reverse engineering project, but I can't find what these components are.  Can someone identify them for me?

The components have the following text on them:

IC #1 = 7HUH

[image: 7HUH]

IC #2 = AAPQ

[image: AAPQ]

Here you can see the 7HUH and AAPQ + external components.

[image: 7HUH and AAPQ and surrounding components]

Comment: Can you show us a schematic of the reverse engineering you have done so far? Sometimes the external components will give you a clue as to the function of the IC so you can narrow it down

Comment: Also, if you are reverse engineering the item you presumably have some idea what the device is for and what that part of the circuit is supposed to be doing. All this information would give useful clues.

Comment: IC1 could be TI TL4050B25QDCKRQ1. IC2 could be MAXIM MAX6826.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/CXVF2pj.png

Comment: @DennisdeGraaf Related: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/334128/how-do-i-identify-smd-components-or-how-do-i-identify-any-component/334129#334129

Comment: @winny post that as an answer

Comment: Thanks for your help But I have tried it this way ( https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/334128/how-do-i-identify-smd-components-or-how-do-i-identify-any-component/334129#334129 )

Comment: I upvoted this question for doing it completely right. Close, clear shots of the components in question and one clear shot showing the board they are assembled on, with pointers.

Comment: I doubt the TL4050B25Q because it only uses two of the five leads. In that ciurcuit, all leads are connected. I also doubt the MAX6826 because it has 6 leads.

Comment: @Janka Thank you for your respond. But the pins 2,4 and 5 from the TL4050B25Q are not connected in the datasheet and are connected in the PCB.

Comment: Yes, exactly. That's why I doubt winny's answer in the comment is correct.

Comment: These are definitely not the "tiny logic" chips. The tiny logic has GND on pin3 and VCC on pin5; the left IC has GND on Pin4, and the right one has it in reverse. I think the left one could be a voltage-reset supervisor.

Answer (score 3):

For the AAPQ I found:

MCP6001T-I/OT which is a SOT23-5 from Microchip and has a marking type "AANN" with NN lot/date code.
[MCP6001T-I/OT datasheet](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/MCP6001-1R-1U-2-4-1-MHz-Low-Power-Op-Amp-DS20001733L.pdf)

[image: photo of device]

Image source: [LCSC - Microchip Tech MCP6001T-I/OT](https://www.lcsc.com/product-detail/Operational-Amplifier_Microchip-Tech-MCP6001T-I-OT_C116490.html)

For the 7HUH I found:

24AA64T-I/OT which is a SOT23-5 from Microchip and has a marking type "7HNN" with NN lot/date code.

[24AA64T-I/OT datasheet](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/MPD/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/24AA64-24FC64-24LC64-64-Kbit-I2C-Serial-EEPROM-20001189U.pdf)

[image: photo of device]

Image source: [Taobao - Shenzhen Chenghao Jiaye Electronics, 24AA64T-I/OT 24AA64-I/OT SOT23-5](https://www.taobao.com/list/item/665200659347.htm?spm=a21wu.10013406.taglist-content.11.658b25bekN5Hje)

(not great picture but couldn't find any other)