# Identify SOT-563 device with top code 49K

Tags: identification, surface-mount

[image: PCB photo with SOT-563 device marked]

Please help me to identify this SOT-563 device with top code 49K

Comment: @AdhePion The dot is a pin marker, you might want to try https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/334128/how-do-i-identify-smd-components-or-how-do-i-identify-any-component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first result on google points to a SSI3439L N&P Channel Mosfet.

see Datasheet [here](http://www.secosgmbh.com/datasheet/products/MOSFET/SOT-563/SSI3439J.pdf)

Comment: thank you for helping my question. other than SSI3439L (equation), because I find it hard to get it.

Comment: @AdhePion - Welcome :-) Please read the [tour] and [help] to learn more about the site and its rules. (a) You talk about "equation" in your comment. I fixed it in your question, and I *think* you mean "part number" here. You certainly *don't* mean "equation" - that's a mis-translation. (b) Your comment *seems* to be asking for alternative parts because you "*find it hard to get*" the original device. It is difficult to help with that type of (new) question, because we don't know which devices are easier for *you* to get! Note that, as explained in the [tour], shopping questions are off-topic.