# Component recognition from marking code

Tags: identification, uart, ttl, logic-level, markings

I need help to recognize a dead component from a lab instrument control board. It is part of a TTL-serial interface, arguably a logic gate or some level shifter, in a TSSOP-14 package.

You can see the picture below: manufacturer is easy to recognize as Fairchild, now OnSemi, while part of the code has been blown up.

If you know the component, a good search engine or just have good hints, please help!

[image: Blown up component from Fairchild]

Comment: Here is a good referece for doing this in the future: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/334128/how-do-i-identify-smd-components-or-how-do-i-identify-any-component

Comment: Lab instruments are more likely to have useful service manuals available than other kinds of stuff. See if you can find the service manual for this instrument (or call the vendor) and get the part number that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably a low voltage quad 2-input and gate

[74LVX08](https://www.mouser.com/ds/2/149/74LVX08-28554.pdf)

[image]

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126180/is-it-acceptable-to-write-a-thank-you-in-a-comment

Answer (score 0):

Could be an artifact of the photo, but it looks like the symbol after the zero is a 4.
Therefore: LVX04.  As found here at [digikey](https://www.digikey.com/products/en?keywords=lvx04)