# KV7RF SMD Datasheet

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification, datasheet, surface-mount, markings

Can someone identify a 5-Pin IC SMD  with the marking code **KV7RF**? Searching in Google I didn't find anything. Any help on this?

[image]

Comment: A picture worths thousand words.

Comment: Please also add the dimensions of it

Comment: @Huisman Dimensions are like  SOT23-6 SMD

Comment: @LongPham The SMD it too small to take a picture and I don't own an electronic microscope.

Comment: @Maverick - FYI these are the current "[Component Identification Question Guidelines](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6710)". The more information you can supply from that list, the better the chances of identification. I understand the issue about a photo of the actual device (although holding a magnifying glass between camera and PCB can work), supplying PCB photos & description of the product can help to narrow down the type of device. Thanks. (Also see: "[How do I identify SMD components? (or how do I identify any component)](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/334128)")

Comment: @LongPham Photo added.

Comment: @Maverick Thanks for your effort :) It looks like a switching regulator IC to me.

Comment: @LongPham I am curious why this part is not documented! How it is supposed to test it if it's faulty?

Comment: I count 6 pads, but think I only see 5 pins. Did pin 5 of the IC break off?

Comment: @Huisman No, it did not break off. There are two of them on the PCB with on pin off by default. I got some answers from eevblog and they recognize it as a "DC regulator IC" as LongPham mention above like this https://datasheet.lcsc.com/szlcsc/SY8089AAAC_C78988.pdf

Comment: Nice you have found the chip. Please note that when you call this a 6-Pin IC SMD while it has 5 pins, it is confusing.

Comment: @Huisman thanx I fixed the misled 6-Pin description

Comment: Good.  You found it.  Make an answer with that information in it.  Accept the answer.  That finishes things up nice and neat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a "DC regulator IC"

datasheet.lcsc.com/szlcsc/SY8089AAAC_C78988.pdf