# Query regarding unknown component

Tags: audio, identification, components, surface-mount

Hi guys I'm very new to this field and I'm having a problem with my sound devices 664 recorder. There's a faulty component and it needs to be replaced. I couldn't find the component here in the local market, could you please tell me what brand does it belongs from or the product name/ number ? Below I have attached the picture of the component.

[image: failed component]

Comment: I wonder if this Analog switch was zapped by an ESD charged cable plugged into recorder or the 48V phantom power option had an effect.  This IC often used for Mixer switches is only rated for  V+ to V- = 44

Comment: Please add the `identification` tag to your question, and see the  [Identification Question Guidelines](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6710/148777).

Comment: Yeah, what actually happened to this? Was it damaged like this on the board, or did it happen when you pulled it off? I'd be worried about PCB pad damage as well.

Answer (score 4):

Googling 212B does not tell us anything really except that it appears in connection to things.

So if I can narrow down the manufacturer it will be a start, there is a logo on the chip I did not recognize so lets see what it could be. I found the logo from this very [useful answer containing a ton of manufacturer logos](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/334129/45408).

And feeding Google the name Siliconix and 212B I get a good result, I suspect it is a Vishay Siliconix DG212B Improved Quad CMOS Analog Switch.

The datasheet confirms 16 pins, so that's the best confirmation i got without actually having the component in my hand to measure the hopefully not broken part.

Comment: I have a feeling that you also looked at the string "212B"...

Comment: Well yes, it gave nothing on its own. So kind of glossed over that when answering.