# How to read markings on EMI/RFI filter

Tags: capacitor, inductor, markings

I am looking at a 3-pad SMD EMI filter chip (see photo) which is marked on the top with "222J". I am familiar with reading the markings on top of resistors and capacitors, but am not sure how to interpret the markings on a EMI/RFI filter.

[image]

Comment: These values are not standardized and are most likely only meaningful in the context of a manufacturer, you'll need to find the manufacturer: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/334128/how-do-i-identify-smd-components-or-how-do-i-identify-any-component

Comment: no datasheet???

Comment: I ran a reverse image search and I found out the product number. [The datasheet](https://static6.arrow.com/aropdfconversion/436219c9912f51c37364d6b44d50a9b0c0310e40/e9613_acf.pdf) can be found here.

Comment: @KingDuken I updated the question with a photo of the actual part

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an LC feedthru filter which means it is bidirectional.

The 222J refers to 2200 pF shunt cap.
[image]

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBWjQz.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

They cannot control the ferrite inductance L and loss values with J accuracy but they can control the buried cap value.

So one vendor may have a slightly different Series Resonant Frequency than another.

But this TDK part guarantees at least 25 dB attenuation into 50 Ohms from 45 to 105 MHz. Actual could be as much as 30 MHz to 300 MHz for the TDK part.

Comment: How did you determine this was a TDK part?

Comment: I used a TDK datasheet which looked like your original photo, not the actual part. Thanks to @KingDuken 's search.

Comment: I still am not clear on the meaning of the "J"

Comment: Normally a  J suffix after value means 5%  ( F ± 1% G ± 2% J ± 5% K ± 10% M ± 20% )  but it's relation to tolerance of centre notch MHz is unknown to me ( since that depends on LC product), the letter is OEM specific as  many do not use this suffix. But if you find one, then you probably found the OEM.