# Unknown 5-pin opamp / comparator IC with ">10" marking

Tags: operational-amplifier, identification, comparator

I'm trying to figure out what this 5-pin IC from the below image could be:

[image: Unknown IC]

The SMD Package looks to be TSSOP5.

The component is used in the [Kemet SS-430 sensor module](https://content.kemet.com/datasheets/KEM_SE0208_SS.pdf). I think, is part of the output amplification circuit for the [Kemet PL-N823-01](https://content.kemet.com/datasheets/KEM_SE0206_PL.pdf) sensor. My guess is that the IC is some kind of opamp or comparator.

[image: Circuit]

*(rectangles = unmarked SMD parts. They are mostly resistors and capacitors, I think.)*

Could you help me identify this component with the ">10" marking?

Thanks!

PS: 
I would like to use the PL-N823-01 in a project, but unfortunately I did not found a reference design for it yet. So, I'm trying to figure the things out from the SS-430 module.

Answer (score 1):

Hope the following will provide you clues to find the 5 pin device.

I believe their are 2 operational amplifiers and a comparator in the Kemet SS-430 sensor module. Below is circuit diagram that might better represent the SS-430 sensor module.

[image]

The D_Out should be connected to a digital IO pin of a uC. You might be able to connect to A_Out to a A/D on a uC, if A_Out is available.

Hopefully someone in the community might be able to identify the component. If not the community might be able help suggest a equivalent part.

Based on the image below the component might be from Analog Devices

[image]

Based on the following comment I believe the device is an operational amplifier

> The sensor chip PL-N823-01 outputs analog voltage that should be amplified and connected to a MCU’s A/D for filtering and processing and fits the high volume or price sensitive applications and involves some design activity from the customer side.

Suggest reviewing the references help reaching your objective.

Good Luck

**References:**

- [Logos for electronic component manufacturers](https://www.electronicspoint.com/forums/resources/logos-for-electronic-component-manufacturers.47/)
- [Sensors - KEMET](https://ec.kemet.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/4/2019/10/112-FY19-DC-Low-V-DC-Other-Sensors-Final-v2.pdf)
- [Things to Consider When Designing With the KEMET SS-430 Sensor Module](https://www.digikey.com/en/maker/projects/things-to-consider-when-designing-with-the-kemet-ss-430-sensor-module/b4abe77a5ec247adaa147a165ddfcb3f)
- [How do I identify SMD components? (or how do I identify any component)](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/334128/how-do-i-identify-smd-components-or-how-do-i-identify-any-component)

Comment: The AD IC's I've seen a marking like in the picture: a white square with a **filled** triangle in it (or the colours inverted), **not** a >

Comment: So, I did not figured out yet what IC is that. Analog Devices seems to have some op-amps with same package, but the pin-out is sightly different (the power pins are swapped).

However, I took a look with an oscilloscope and the output of the sensor varies at about 650-850mV. That gets into the opamp IC and gets amplified to the range of 800mV-3V. This signal then is fed directly into a PIC12F617 micro-controller, probably into and ADC or comparator.