# Please identify this 8-pin SMT device - markings P636F FDS 6690A

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification

Please assist - I cannot identify this device. I try to label all my SMT components, but this one has slipped through the net.

It appears to have a "f" as a logo; the text blocks are P636F; FDS and 6690A.

Also, as a more general question, what resources are recommended for tracking down such items?

[image: photo of device]

Comment: Regarding your general question - for example, see: "[How do I identify SMD components? (or how do I identify any component)](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/334128)"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google is your first choice. Searching for FDS 6690A brought up [this datasheet](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/FDS6690A-D.PDF) on the first page. The "F" would indicate that it was originally a Fairchild product, which ON semi acquired some time ago.

FDS6690A Single N-Channel, Logic-Level, PowerTrench MOSFET

Comment: Thanks. I was searching on the wrong term - P636F produced nothing.

Comment: Usually one of the markings is a datecode and/or manufacturing location. Searching for *all* the markings will likely get a correct hit.  https://www.google.com/search?q=P636F+FDS+6690A