# Who manufactures this chip? Looking for the data sheet. Top marking "QB52"

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification, components, datasheet

[image: photo of device]

I'm looking for the datasheet of this chip. I don't recognise the manufacturer logo. Does anyone recognise this?

I tried a Google search for "QB52 Chip" but failed.

Comment: What does the circuit do ?

Comment: Related: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/334128/how-do-i-identify-smd-components-or-how-do-i-identify-any-component/334129#334129

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be a voltage regulator:
http://www.elm-tech.com/en/products/voltage-detector/elm75-series/