# SMD component identification - possibly BJT

Tags: transistors, bjt, identification, surface-mount, repair

I found a defective SOT-23 on a broken PCB, but can't identify it. Probably a BJT, but what kind?
The one on the right seems to be the same as the blown one.
[image: blown sot-23]

I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Related: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/334128/how-do-i-identify-smd-components-or-how-do-i-identify-any-component/334129#334129

Comment: If you cant find you can test to see if BJT then which is NPN, PNP then choose high hFE (>200) with low Rce <= 2 Ohms= Vce(sat)/If. For a replacement