# Electronic component name & value to be traced

Tags: transistors, capacitor, integrated-circuit

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_component

What are the best ways to trace the electronic components value, name if the name &  value are not able to be seen on the component itself because of old printed circuit boards?

Examples : capacitor, diode, transistor, integrated circuit etc

Comment: Read the schematic for that PCB.

Comment: Thanks Brian. If the schematic diagram is not available then in that case?

Comment: Hire an experience Electrical Engineering, or an Engineering Consulting Company.

Comment: Related [How to identify components](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/334128/96810)