# What is the datasheet of this component in the photo, with markings 74YH S21B?

Tags: identification, surface-mount

I need the datasheet of an SMD component, on which I can read

```
74YH 
S21B
```

The chip is about 3mm x 3mm and, given its position on the board, has likely something to do with voltage regulation (but I can't be 100% sure).
It has 8 leads.
Please see the attached picture if that helps.

[image: the component to identify is marked 74YH S21B]

I have already explored the component-identification procedures proposed in the following post:
[How do I identify SMD components? (or how do I identify any component)](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/334128/how-do-i-identify-smd-components-or-how-do-i-identify-any-component)
but nothing clear came out (at best, hundreds of potential results...).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Very probably an [LM3488](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/snvs089o/snvs089o.pdf), a DC/DC converter controller IC; those are marked S21B. The top line of the markings varies.

Not *entirely* sure, though.

Comment: I think you are correct e.g. [OP's photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LcUOI.jpg) shows pins 4 & 5 connected, which fits with that IC you identified (pin 4 = AGND, pin 5 = PGND) and pin 1 for that IC is I_SEN which we expect to be connected to a low value resistor - and we *do* see it connected to a 0.1 ohm resistor in the photo. The capacitor & resistor in the lower left of the photo, would match the RC network expected to be connected to pin 2 (COMP). Some traces (and more of the surrounding components) aren't visible in the photo, but on the supplied info from the OP, this get my vote :-)

Comment: Thanks, FYI I find all the components about it making a SEPIC, so this makes a lot of sense!