# To-scale images useful for comparing sizes of small (SOT23 and smaller) packages typical for discrete transistors or diodes?

Tags: packages

Is there a to-scale image available somewhere that shows SOT23, SOT323, SOT523, etc. packages used typically for discrete transistors or diodes, so that someone without access to a PCB layout program could compare them?

All I could find is https://www.centralsemi.com/PDFs/literature/Diodes_SF_English_PDF_Version.pdf which is helpful for comparing the larger packages (D2PAK, DPAK, etc.) but not the smaller ones.

(And https://www.mccsemi.com/pdf/SMDDimensionSelectionGuide.pdf where the displayed images are not accurate in relative size)

---

For example, here is [one from ON Semi covering 6-pin packages](https://www.onsemi.com/site/cdroms/micropackages/pdf-docs/onsemi/SOT563%20footprint-prof%23B3380.pdf)

[image]

Comment: Maybe here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/334128/how-do-i-identify-smd-components-or-how-do-i-identify-any-component/334129#334129

Comment: what do you mean with "to scale"? A digital photo is never "to scale", it's always as much to scale as you scale it; physical size is not a property of digital images. Someone comparing footprints with design tools wants a *dimensional drawing*, so the second link is actually what you're looking for.

Comment: If you have CAD models of these packages, e.g. in Inventor, as well as a functional printer that doesn't have print scale issues, printing a 1:1 scale drawing of top/side/front views is a perfectly well-supported functionality. On that note, if you are OK with just the PCB footprint layers (pads, maybe mask + silk), you can do the same thing but print the PDF plot of a PCB with the relevant footprints.

Comment: No, I do not want a dimensional drawing, that is not enough. I want a drawing where each package has the same scale, so if one part X is twice as big as another part Y, then X shows up in the image twice as big as Y. The MCC Semi PDF does not have that property.

Comment: @nanofarad I have no access to CAD software; I work with people who do but they are all busy, and I'm just looking for a reference image that shows relative package sizes.

Comment: @MarcusMüller to scale just means that the drawing and the real objects in that drawing have dimensions related by a single constant of proportionality.

Comment: @VoltageSpike no -- that NXP graphic does not maintain the same scale ratio across all packages (see for example SOT23 and Power-SO8 -- a SOT23's dimensions are smaller but in the image it is larger)

Comment: @JasonS Install KiCAD, it's free and easy. Otherwise, something like [this](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/digi-key-electronics/PCB-RULER-12INCH/5767550) is very handy to have; it's a ruler with a bunch of common transistor/diode/passive/IC packages on it as well as a bunch of other things that are handy for making circuit boards.

Answer (score 7):

When in doubt, make one.

[image]

Using KiCad to place the desired components and then plotting the fab layer (with pad sketch) to produce the required PDF, which should print 1:1

https://smallpdf.com/shared#st=36d0795c-1b5a-4e5b-9dd6-5fab619e0258&fn=-F_Fab.pdf&ct=1615566497945&tl=share-document&rf=link

Answer (score 5):

There aren't images with *all smt packages* just some of them, here are a few examples.

[image]
Source: https://passive-components.eu/good-things-come-in-small-packages-a-capacitor-technology-update/

[image]
Source: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/34/SMT_sizes%2C_based_on_original_by_Zureks.svg

Comment: thanks, that's along the lines I'm looking for, but particularly for small discrete diodes and transistors. (i've clarified in the question)