# How can I Identify this IC marked SDA

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification

I'm trying to find what this part could be. I'm pretty sure the packaging is SOT-23-6 based on measurements I took (about 3.5mm by 4.5mm counting the length of the pins). I know that the middle top and bottom pins are Vcc and GND, it looks like bottom left is the input and top left is the output. My guess for top right would be an enable pin because most things on this board have them. I took measurements while the board was running and measured 2.7V DC on bottom left and 1.35V DC top left. I measured top right and also got 2.7V DC.

[image]

There are two right next to each other with their outputs tied together and running into an op-amp while another IC (which happens to be unidentified) is connected to both of their top right pins. When I was measuring it seemed like only one was getting anything in its input at any given time but I'm not 100% sure of that. I've searched based on top marking and can't find anything that makes sense as well as trying to search some voltage regulators using the measured dimensions and one output. Any help with where I can go next would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you see this: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/334129/107479?

Comment: @dim I have been using that post to help me search, but it gets difficult when there isn't a manufacturer's mark and searching the top mark doesn't get me anywhere. I'm also not particularly good at recognizing the function of a part even if I've gathered information about its pins, but I'm working on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ADG751](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADG751.pdf) from analog devices comes in that package with those markings and the power pin locations seem to match.

Comment: That appears to be the part! The help is much appreciated.