# Found these supposed "op amps." Does anyone know how I can identify them properly?

Tags: operational-amplifier, identification

I've been given these components and couldn't find any info about them aside from a couple of Amazon articles of them stating that they were op amps.

No matter how many DIP 14 standard op amp pin-outs I tried however, these op amps just never seemed to work properly.

Assuming that they are not fried, does anyone have any tips on how to identify them?

The DIP 14 one (306 2741EC) has "S741" written on its backside if that would help.

[image: the supposed op amp:]

[image: The supposed comparator]

Comment: The TO-5 one may be an LM318 clone but I've never seen a "306" opamp. (LM301 yes, but if there's an LM306 it's a rarity). Or they may be something else altogether.

Comment: Possibly the "2741" implies a dual or quad 741? Did you already try this pinout: https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm148-n.pdf

Comment: The logo (circle with internal three radial lines, or three circle segments) looks similar to the Rockwell logo; see also the canonical identification question https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/334128/how-do-i-identify-smd-components-or-how-do-i-identify-any-component

Comment: @MarkU yes I did unfortunately.

Comment: Looks like Thompson CSF to me. Probably from the 70’s to early 80’s. They are now known as ST microelectronics.

Comment: Logo could be mostek; but they may be more a vintage memory company, probably not opamp... http://www.bitsavers.org/components/mostek/_dataBooks/  ...

Comment: Octopart recognizes "STMicroelectronics SFC2741DC" as a valid part...

Comment: @MarkU I am not very familiar with octopart but was the component recognized as an op amp?

Comment: Octopart is an aggregator that searches for stock in distributors, unfortunately they don't have the datasheets. I think Kartman is on the right track, STM was apparently once Thompson CSF / Mostek; the logo looks right, I'm looking into old databook on bitsavers.org -- http://www.bitsavers.org/components/thomson/_dataBooks/1987_Thomson-Mostek_Microprocessors_and_Peripherals.pdf -- mmm, no op amps there...

Comment: ... but datahseetarchive.org (my personal nemesis) has a fragment of a datasheet at https://www.datasheetarchive.com/pdf/download.php?id=ae4059adc91de15321de92050ff59d5eff202c&type=M&term=sfc2741 which seems to list the SFC 2741 part number, and says it's an op amp. Unfortunately they only have two pages of part numbers, not a complete datasheet, and no pinout.  It's on page 162 of *something* but they don't say what manufacturer, what databook, what year of publication. So a near miss but not really useful.

Comment: https://www.ebay.com/itm/UA741CDP-IC-General-purpose-single-OP-AMP-DIP-14-Thomson-/362468879212?_ul=BR

Comment: [1979 IC Master](http://www.bitsavers.org/components/icMaster/1979_IC_Master.pdf) (*big pdf, 183,923,985 bytes*) lists **SFC2741** as a second-source (clone) of **LM741 op amp**, made by a company called **NPC (Nucleonic Products Co.)** (page 863-30; page 752 of the pdf) and NPC **SFC2710** as a second-source of **LM710 comparator** (page 845-24, page 734 of the pdf). IC master does contain some datasheets, but I don't see any of NPC's datasheets. (This big, heavy IC Master book was "the internet all printed out", before there was internet.)

Comment: Just buy new parts from reputable dealers.

Answer (score 4):

According to [IC Master 1984](https://archive.org/details/bitsavers_icMaster19_159569496/page/n1743/mode/2up), SFC2741 (made by Thomson-CSF) is an alternative for the [μA741](https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/25555/STMICROELECTRONICS/UA741.html) op amp, and SFC710 is an alternative for the [μA710](https://cdn.datasheetspdf.com/pdf-down/U/A/7/UA710_FairchildSemiconductor.pdf) comparator.

[image]

ETA: found a cross-reference that confirms these chips are equivalent:-

[SGS THOMSON-CSF (SESCOSEM) Linear integrated circuits ( Circuits intégrés linéaires) 1976](http://matthieu.benoit.free.fr/cross/data_sheets/THOMSON-CSF1976.htm)

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried this pinout to no avail, I tested the IC both in Comparator and unity follower modes and the output is just random noise , these chips might be fried after all , I appreciate the effort everyone put into this but I think I'll be better off just buying op amps.