# SMD marking code 63M09

Tags: identification

I received chips different from chips that I ordered. Already asked for refund.
But I am curious what these chips actually do. I searched several SMD code books, but had no luck. Does anybody have any clue what they could be?

It's SOT-23-6, Marking code 63M09.
[image]

I have ordered battery ballancer ICs [HY2213-BB3A](https://cdn.datasheetspdf.com/pdf-down/H/Y/2/HY2213-HYCON.pdf).
But I do not think the chips I received are just some clones, because I measured no diode drop across pins 2-3 (there should be a diode internally). So I assume those are completely different chips.

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/334129/107479

Comment: Im not sure at all, but often on those packages there are Fets or Jfets

Answer (score 2):

I probably found a good candidate.
I googled and found some strange page which is referring "63M09" and "OB2263MP". So it could be [OB2263MP](https://file.yizimg.com/332467/2010080308450435.pdf) (Current Mode PWM Controller).
It's SOT-23-6, and I measured some diode drops and resistances across certain pins and measured values agree with internal schematic of this chip. So it is pretty much this chip. I am not 100% sure, I would have to test that chip in some circuit to be 100% sure.

Comment: OB 2263 mp is correct part no. For 63mo9
I have used it in 12v 3amp power supply