# Need Help Identifying - Pentair pool automation motherboard

Tags: capacitor, surface-mount, fuses

Hoping someone can help me identify the component in this picture.  This is a Pentair pool automation motherboard - model number 520073.  The top part of the photo shows what I believe is a capacitor that has 'blown', and the bottom portion of the photo shows another area of the same board with the same component that hasn't 'blown'.  The only reason I know both components are the same is because I was able to find a photo via internet search with high enough resolution to know that the numbers on top of the components are the same.

At first, I thought it was maybe a fuse, but there's no continuity on the good component, so believe it must be a capacitor.

While it's a little blurry, the numbers on the component are 47 and 6V.

Any guidance would be appreciated!

[image]

[image]

Comment: 47uF 6V Tantalum Electrolytic capacitor. You'll have to measure the physical dimensions to get an exact match. A replacement with a higher voltage rating would be fine.

Comment: Related: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/334128/how-do-i-identify-smd-components-or-how-do-i-identify-any-component/334129#334129