# Identify these two battery protection cutoff board components?

Tags: identification

Could you please help identify these two components? It is a circuit for low voltage battery protection cutoff.

1. First pic, this black box it is located between Vin somewhere i cannot figure out (the trace shown in 3rd image) . and i donot know how many pins it has

   [image]
2. Second pic, these 2 ICs are the same SOT-23-6 (I think). Named 0266J or 0265J or 02S6J. they are located near a MSP430 microcontroller.

   [image]

**EDIT: I have uploaded a third pic to show the black box from the side maybe it will give a clue about its height and pins ?!**

[image]

Comment: How many pins does the 'black box' have, and what are they connected to?

Comment: @BruceAbbott , i have edited the question

Comment: this is a 4layer board thats why i cannot flow the where the via is going . but right side  in pic3 or left side in pic 1 is certainly connected to Vin. my intuition says it is a snubber Resistor or capacitor maybe ??

Comment: Related: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/334128/how-do-i-identify-smd-components-or-how-do-i-identify-any-component/334129#334129 DMMs can be helpful for tracking down traces on breadboards

Comment: Also, for questions like these dimensions are needed

Comment: Too many connections to be a capacitor. Perhaps a relay?

Comment: @VoltageSpike i tried using DMM in resistance mode it showed more than 2.5Mega ohm . and in capacitance mode nothing .

Comment: @BruceAbbott the problem is that the pins are hidden under neath so i donot even know how many pins it has . i am thinking about using hot air to remove it

Comment: @VoltageSpike length : 12mm . width 6mm at base 4mm at top . height is  7mm

Answer (score 3):

I think your black box may be a low signal relay from Omron. Check this [datasheet](https://octopart.com/datasheet/g6a274pstusdc5byomr-omron-689361) out. It has the A2 and the C5BY as part of the part#.

For the ICs, I think they may be TI's TLV62569 or TLV62568 buck converters. Here's the datasheet for [both](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlv62569.pdf?ts=1654973831759) of [them](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlv62568.pdf?ts=1655019960655). There is also a chance (*probably unlikely*) that the ICs are New Japan Radio's [NJM2561](https://octopart.com/datasheet/njm2561f1-te1-new+japan+radio-840362) but I can't give a good answer unless I know what the circuit was a part of. Hope this helps!

Comment: The Omron G6A is only available in through hole packages so I'd expect this is something else [see here for the omron LSR lineup](https://components.omron.com/us-en/products/relays/signal-relays/signal-relays)

Comment: the black box looks like it has only 2 connections , so probably not  a relay . the other ics are 100% not buck converters they are connected to microcontroller . they might be voltage reference . but thanks for trying to help :)