# What are these two components?

Tags: pcb, integrated-circuit, identification, components

I need to replace these two components but searching for the markings on them yields no results. Does anyone know what they are?

[image]

Comment: Asking for replacement possibilities is off-topic here; best stick to just identifying them.

Comment: @ocrdu The OP is not necessarily asking for a second source, they might just want to replace the broken parts on their PCB but fails to identify them. That's on-topic.

Comment: Since these are fairly certain to be parts from ON Semi I'd just ask their support. Likely like some BJTs or MOSFETS.

Comment: @Lundin: I know, hence my question edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First identified the logo as ON Semi.

On the right: [On Semi MTD10N10EL](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/MTD10N10EL-D.PDF) (found with "ON SEMI marking 10N)

On the left: [On Semi MTD3055VL](https://www.mouser.de/datasheet/2/308/1/MTD3055VL_D-1811720.pdf) (after realizing how the first marking worked, searched on the On Semi site for 3055VL. But the link to the datasheet is not working there anymore)

For more tips on how to identify components look at this [question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/334128/how-do-i-identify-smd-components-or-how-do-i-identify-any-component).

Comment: So the "246" and "247" is just for show?

Comment: No, it's the datecode as indicated in the datasheets I linked to. 2 is the year and 47 is the work week.