# How to know part number of an unknown chip from IC marking?

Tags: audio, integrated-circuit, datasheet

I am trying to get information from top mark of an IC.
I couldn't find it from this article.
[How do I identify SMD components? (or how do I identify any component)](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/334128/how-do-i-identify-smd-components-or-how-do-i-identify-any-component?noredirect=1&lq=1)
Its manufacturers are JRC.
Which chips have these top mark?
A097F
JRC

and

A098F
JRC

I couldn't find any result from google.
I think this chip is related to audio circuit.

Comment: Not every chip has a publicly available datasheet, especially if it is some custom application-specific one.

Comment: I just want to know part number of these chips

Comment: post a hi res pic of the component. And also dimensions. That might help in locating it. Why do you say it's JRC ?

Comment: thanks I already got full information, it was opamp of JRC.