# Identification of ABLIC (Seiko Instruments) brand components

Tags: voltage-regulator, integrated-circuit, identification, components, markings

Lately I've been looking for components of the brand ABLIC (Seiko Instruments).
On the following examples, i was only able to identify the brand.
However I cannot find a methodology to find the components corresponding to the markings.

Do you know of an effective way to find the exact designations of this brand components?

Herafter a couple of examples:

SOT89-5 example (similar component marking here: [ABLIC S-1172B12-U5T1G](https://es.aliexpress.com/i/1005003187588347.html))

[image]

SOT23-6 example (similar marking found here : [ABLIC S-8261AAGMD-G2GT2S](https://jlcpcb.com/partdetail/ABLIC-S_8261AAGMDG2GT2S/C468209))

[image]

SOT23-5 example (similar marking found here: [ABLIC S-1167B18-M5T1U](https://jlcpcb.com/partdetail/Ablic-S_1167B18M5T1U/C140906))

[image]

Comment: The answer [How do I identify SMD components? (or how do I identify any component)](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/334129/101063) has some suggestions. It is more problematic if there is no manufacturer's logo marked on small parts.

Comment: It's not a problem of  logo identification, the brand is ABLIC for sure but the part number identification.