# What is this shorted diode from a Bosch BMS for an eBike?

Tags: diodes, identification, repair, bms

[image]

I am currently trying to repair a Bosch BMS from an ebike and found a shorted diode so far.

I can't figure out what exact model the diode is can anybody help me to identify it?

Comment: I suggest that you change the question title from "help me find" (shopping question) to "help me identify"  (information question) and add in the markings from the component so that the reader doesn't have to open the question to know what you are asking about.

Comment: Dimensions of capsule? Where does it sit in the circuit?

Comment: I would simply recommend changing the title to eliminate the "can someone..." portion entirely, because otherwise the answer becomes simply "yes" or "maybe."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a [FSS16 HE3 TRT*](https://www.fagorelectronica.com/site/templates/resources/semiconductores/data-sheets/fss1.pdf) diode from FAGOR.
I suggest HE3 suffix as you mentionned that your board is manufactured by Bosch (automotive).

Explanation of the marking available [here](https://www.fagorelectronica.com/site/assets/files/6359/fagor-marking.pdf)
[image]

Comment: Thanks is there a trick to figure stuff like this out? I was trying to find a big list with part manufactuers logos but wasnt successful.

Comment: @Bobtimus [How do I identify SMD components? (or how do I identify any component)](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/334129/101063) has logos for multiple manufacturers.

Comment: @Bobtimus Experience plays a lot to be honest, but search by logo is a good choice in that case, you can try to insert your image in google image, browse logos sites, fagor logo is here for instance https://www.ecadata.de/herst/myshowlogo.php?F_SPRACHE=2