SOT23-6 IC marked 854A
please identify SOT23-6 ICs with markings 179A and 854A. These are mounted on a BLDC ceiling fan controller kit's power supply section. The power supply is 220V AC input and 24V DC output.
Thanks
P.S. The first lines are 636019 and 631020 respectively.




Check https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/334128/107479 for methods to identify components

To get good answers, you need to ask good questions. Your question is lacking (a) closeup photo which show the markings in good quality, (b) a photo of the complete PCB, (c) a schematic or drawing of the electric components, (d) mechanical dimensions and pincount of your components. This will help others to answer your question precisly.

Following @HansmitmFlammenwerfer good points, please make sure that posted photos aren't a giant picture of your fingers. Place the object on a plain background, like an anti-static mat/bag or a sheet of white A4 paper. Crop the photos to only show the relevant components, so readers aren't scrolling past useless photo content to read the text here. Thanks.

Can you add what to upper line of the markings reads? It's hard to see in the picture and it's probably the relevant information.

To make it more clear: These are likely On-Bright parts. The first two or three characters of the first line are the relevant code. The rest is useless for identification. Since these characters are not readable in your picture, you won't get an answer.

Thanks for adding the marking information, but his means your question is a duplicate of this one: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/723687/flyback-controller-ic-identification#723694
